# get_posts dont work with post__in

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$lessons_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_course-lessons-1', true );
$posts = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'courses', 'post__in' => array( $lessons_id ) ) );
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post );
echo get_the_title();
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

If you put the variable in post__in does not work, it only returns the first value. But getting `'post__in' => array (985,987,254)` works. I already echoed the variable, and the output is exactly the same as 985,987,254.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `true`as 3rd parameter for `get_post_meta` which means your return value will always be a single value, not an array. Try to replace your first line with :

```
$lessons_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_course-lessons-1', false );
```